# How would I get a specific phrase out of a string? Python Language

Tags: python, url

I would like to write a function when it's given a URL as a string, parses out just the domain name and returns it as a string.

```
url = "http://google.com/youtube/win" > domain name = "google"
url = "http://www.foodpub.com/home" > domain name = "foodpub"
url = "http://www.foodpub.com/home" > domain name = "foodpub"
url = "https://www.games.com" > domain name = "games"`
```

I have figure that you would need to import 'from urllib.parse import urlparse'

Comment: What about `www.google.co.uk`? The general rules are different for every top-level domain.

Comment: The domain name of "google.com" is not "google", it is "google.com". You can use the `hostname` property of what urllib provides but separating out just part of the domain name is dangerous. You probably don't want to confuse "google.xxx" with "google.com".